# vscode: Can't break on any breakpoint with Visual Studio code when launching with nodemon

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, nodemon

VSCode Version: 1.10.2
OS Version: Windows 7 Profesionnal, SP1
Node version: 6.10.0

Hi everyone.

I'm trying to debug typescript code (or javascript code) in server side with visual studio code, when launching it with nodemon. I've added a new configuration in launch.json which looks like this:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch server with Nodemon",
      "runtimeExecutable": "nodemon",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--debug=5858"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server.ts",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 5858,
      "console": "integratedTerminal",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/build/**/*.js"]
    }
```

I have a task in vscode that is running tsc that builds javascript files properly. This is my current task config:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "command": "tsc",
  "isShellCommand": true,
  "args": ["-p", "."],
  "showOutput": "silent",
  "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

The javascript files are generated as expected when I change a typescript file.
And the nodejs server is restarting as expected when a javascript file is generated.

But I am not able to break on any breakpoint (on typescript files or javascript files).

Can you tell me please if it is an issue or if there is something I am missing ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: To debug i usually just write this on my console:

node --inspect --debug-brk my-file.js

Grab the link, paste it on my browser and that's it.

Comment: Also the statement `debugger` is ignored. When launching without nodemon, `program` (in *launch.js*) must be set to the typescript file, and `outFiles` has to specify the mapping to the generated javascript file. But how to do that when launching with `nodemon`?

Comment: @ManfredSteiner: You can see my answer below...Maybe it will answer your question.. But in resume, in your tsconfig.json, you have to set the "outDir" option to the path where you want to output your js files (like for example: "outDir":"./build"). Then, in your launch.json, set the "outFiles" option to the same path than setted before, but you have to use blob regular expression to select them all (see my config below). Also, set the "sourceMaps" option to true in your launch.json. I hope it will help you

Comment: @TiagoBértolo: I'm not sure this is the proper way to debug typescript/javascript code in the vscode IDE. The idea is to debug inside visual studio code and to reach breakpoints in the editor files. I don't understand how your solution resolves my issue.. But anyway, you can see my answer below if you need to debug and break on breakpoints in vscode.

Comment: @Philoufelin i was telling you to debug your app with Chrome Dev Tools without vscode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks that there is an issue in vscode (Issue opened by on github [here][1]) . But for now, the workaround is to set the protocol in the configuration (launch.json) to "inspector". With this option, the breakpoints is now reached properly.

Also, change the **"--debug=5858"** in the "runtimeArgs" option to **"--inspect=5858"**

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch server with Nodemon",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--inspect=5858"
  ],
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server.ts",
  "restart": true,
  "port": 5858,
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/build/**/*.js"],
  "sourceMaps": true
},
```

Also, after that, if you have a flashing message error telling you:

> Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858)

It means that your program is too short and that debugger has not enough time to break on your breakpoint. To resolve that, add a second runtime argument to option "runtimeArgs": **"--debug-brk"** and set too **"stopOnEntry"** option to **true**

The final configuration should looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch server with Nodemon",
  "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
  "runtimeArgs": [
    "--inspect=5858",
    "--debug-brk"
  ],
  "stopOnEntry": true,
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server.ts",
  "restart": true,
  "port": 5858,
  "protocol": "inspector",
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
  "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/build/**/*.js"],
  "sourceMaps": true
}
```

It should break on the first line of your entry javascript file. Then you can press F5 and it will reach your own breakpoint.

If you don't want to press F5 each time you run your program, you can instead embed your main entry code inside a setTimeOut function with at least 1000 ms of timeout.

All these options will give enough of time to vscode to break on your breakpoints.

://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23900 "GitHub Issue"

Comment: Note for Deno it's `--inspect-brk`.

Answer (score 2):

@ManfredSteiner

I had this issue recently too. I guess you've tried to break just in the beginning of your entry file (main.ts). I've heard that we have this error message because the program is too short and terminates before the debugger can attach successfully. You have 2 solutions:

- First, put your entry code inside a setTimeOut function with at least 1000 ms. It should give enough of time to debugger to attach to your program.
- The second solution is to set to your launch.json the options: "stopOnEntry" to "true" and set the runtimeArgs option to ["--inspect=5858", "--debug-brk"].

Like this:

`"configurations": [
   {
     "type": "node",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "nodemon",
     "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
     "runtimeArgs": [
       "--inspect=5858",
       "--debug-brk"
     ],
     "stopOnEntry": true,
     "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server/main.ts",
     "restart": true,
     "port": 5858,
     "protocol": "inspector",
     "console": "integratedTerminal",
     "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
     "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"],
     "sourceMaps": true
   }
 ]`

It will break at the first line of your main.js and then, by pressing F5, you will be able to break on your own breakpoint in main.ts. If you don't want, each time you run your program, to press F5 until it reaches your breakpoint, I suggest you to use the first solution (Embed your main.ts entry code inside a setTimeOut function with a least 1000 ms). I hope it will help you

Comment: This setting is working. Output is visible in tab TERMINAL, and program execution breaks properly on breakpoints. Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

@Philoufelin, thanks for your effort. I have now tested them following your suggestions.

... added to file **tsconfig.json**

```
"outDir": "./dist"
```

snapshot from file **launch.json**

```
"configurations": [
   {  
     "type": "node",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "nodemon",
     "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/nodemon",
     "runtimeArgs": [ "--inspect=5858" ],
     "program": "${workspaceRoot}/src/server/main.ts",
     "restart": true,
     "port": 5858,
     "protocol": "inspector",
     "console": "integratedTerminal",
     "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
     "outFiles": ["${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"],
     "sourceMaps": true
   }
 ]
```

But it does not work. After 10s vscode flashes the message ...
*Cannot connect to runtime process, timeout after 10000 ms - (reason: Cannot connect to the target: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5858)*

*nodemon* also prints out the following line on start:
`chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:5858/a0f8f52a-47ec-4ddb-9f03-4eb1c97ef8aa`

I tried this link in chromium, attachment works, but debugger statements or breakpoints are ignored.

I observed a further difference to normal debugging with vscode. Normal debugging starts in the DEBUG CONSOLE tab. Launching nodemon starts in the TERMINAL tab.